# Spring Session Redis serializer SerializationException

Tags: spring, tomcat, redis, spring-session

In an attempt to externalize tomcat session for my existing application I am trying the Spring Session Redis solution. After following the steps to include necessary dependencies in pom.xml like so :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

adding the springSessionRepositoryFilter in web.xml like this :

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and adding the following in Spring XML configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:port="${spring.redis.port}"/>
```

and building and deploying on to tomcat, this is the error I am getting :

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient
```

Any suggestion to or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !!
Also attached are my pom.xml entries :
[pom.xml entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QARJc.png)

Comment: can you post full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: `java.io.NotSerializableException` I'm guessing whatever object you're trying to save as a session state is not serializable. Post more details about the mechanics of saving the session state

Answer (score 2):

## Serializable

I solved by adding `Serializable` to my entity to be like below:

```
public class YourEntity implements Serializable{}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your exception, com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient is not serializable because it did not implemented java.io.Serializable.

**You need to serialize ApacheHttpClient** in some other way, because it is a **3rd party** library.

You can use `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` from the **Jackson library** to achieve this.

Please refer this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_object_serialization.htm).

You could also try SerializableEntity class shipped with HttpClient.

```
httpost.setEntity(new SerializableEntity(mySerializableObj, false));
```

Below are the **general** approaches to make a class serializable.

- if the class is yours, make it Serializable ( this is **not** your case)
- if the class is **3rd party**, but you don't need it in the serialized form, mark the field as **transient**
- if you need its data and it's third party, consider
  other means of serialization, like **JSON, XML,BSON, MessagePack** etc.
  where you can get 3rd party objects serialized without modifying
  their definitions.

Comment: after trying your suggestion, now I get the following errors/exceptions... I am wondering if I am running into compatibility issues with Spring Session...  'code' org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Answer (score 1):

Just want to illustrate one of the possible solutions here. For brevity, I assume you are using spring-boot.

Essentially, spring boot auto-configures the beans defined in `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` class when you annotate your application with `@EnableRedisHttpSession`. And within the autoconfigured beans, `sessionRedisTemplate` is what you want customize the serializer. The codes below shows the default bean definition provided by `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration`.

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate(
        RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    if (this.defaultRedisSerializer != null) {
        template.setDefaultSerializer(this.defaultRedisSerializer);
    }
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

To override this bean config, simple declare a bean named `sessionRedisTemplate` in one of your @Configuration classes (e.g., HttpSessionConfig), and Spring-boot will does the magic to override its default setting. Here, I demo it with a `GenericJackson2JsonSerializer`.

```
@Configuration
public class HttpSessionConfig {

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate(
        RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return template;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had also same issue, and making the class `Serializable` solved my problem.

Comment: I think the important note here is that the class causing the OP's serialization exception is from an external library, so it can't simply be updated as `serializable`

Answer (score 0):

Your entity should implement `Serializable` interface.